# Get total number of rows from joined record in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

It's pretty strange, I am using group_by and join.

Here is the query I have:

```
SELECT *
FROM (`emp_skills` ES)
INNER JOIN `employee` E ON `E`.`employee_id`= `ES`.`employee_id`
INNER JOIN `ml_skill_type` MLST ON `MLST`.`skill_type_id` = `ES`.`ml_skill_type_id`
INNER JOIN `employment` ET ON `ET`.`employee_id` = `E`.`employee_id`
INNER JOIN `position_management` PM ON `PM`.`employement_id`=`ET`.`employment_id` AND PM.current=1
INNER JOIN `ml_designations` MLD ON `MLD`.`ml_designation_id`=`PM`.`ml_designation_id`
LEFT JOIN `assign_job` AJ ON `AJ`.`employee_id` = `E`.`employee_id`
LEFT JOIN `ml_projects` MLP ON `MLP`.`project_id` = `AJ`.`project_id`
GROUP BY `E`.`employee_id`
```

And here is there result I am getting so far:

[image]

but if I use this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS numrows
```

then my query becomes:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS numrows
FROM (`emp_skills` ES)
INNER JOIN `employee` E ON `E`.`employee_id`= `ES`.`employee_id`
INNER JOIN `ml_skill_type` MLST ON `MLST`.`skill_type_id` = `ES`.`ml_skill_type_id`
INNER JOIN `employment` ET ON `ET`.`employee_id` = `E`.`employee_id`
INNER JOIN `position_management` PM ON `PM`.`employement_id`=`ET`.`employment_id` AND PM.current=1
INNER JOIN `ml_designations` MLD ON `MLD`.`ml_designation_id`=`PM`.`ml_designation_id`
LEFT JOIN `assign_job` AJ ON `AJ`.`employee_id` = `E`.`employee_id`
LEFT JOIN `ml_projects` MLP ON `MLP`.`project_id` = `AJ`.`project_id`
GROUP BY `E`.`employee_id`
```

And this is the strange result I am getting, which I should get only 1 column and row I guess to show me total rows:

[image]

How to fix this query?

### Update

Here is more explanation. This is the query with commented out group_concat and group_by

```
SELECT 
`E`.`employee_id`,
`E`.`full_name`,
`MLD`.`designation_name`#,
#GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT MLP.project_title) AS Projects,
#GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT MLST.skill_name) AS EmployeeSkills
FROM (`emp_skills` ES)
INNER JOIN `employee` E ON `E`.`employee_id`= `ES`.`employee_id`
INNER JOIN `ml_skill_type` MLST ON `MLST`.`skill_type_id` = `ES`.`ml_skill_type_id`
INNER JOIN `employment` ET ON `ET`.`employee_id` = `E`.`employee_id`
INNER JOIN `position_management` PM ON `PM`.`employement_id`=`ET`.`employment_id` AND PM.current=1
INNER JOIN `ml_designations` MLD ON `MLD`.`ml_designation_id`=`PM`.`ml_designation_id`
LEFT JOIN `assign_job` AJ ON `AJ`.`employee_id` = `E`.`employee_id`
LEFT JOIN `ml_projects` MLP ON `MLP`.`project_id` = `AJ`.`project_id`
#GROUP BY `E`.`employee_id`
LIMIT 25
```

and here is its result:

[image]

In above image there are 16 records which count can show fine. But if used group_concat and group_by I get 6 records.

[image]

which I actually want, I don't want repeated employee names, instead I want comma separated values etc.

But how to know how many rows query is returning from MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know the total count you need to remove the `GROUP BY E.employee_id` at the end. Right now you're getting the aggregated count per distinct `employee_id`, not the total count.

Comment: but that shows me 16 records while i get 6 records with group by??  so i want to get the number of rows that i am getting as it will be used in pagination..

Comment: that 16 recors with without COUNT(*) while COUNT(*) will give you one row with content '16', right?

Comment: yes. True, but i dont want 16 records?? i mean i dont want repetion thats why i am using group_by and group_concat?
How to solve this issue then?

Comment: You want a single row that contains a single field the value '16' here, right? So combine `COUNT(*)` with removing the `GROUP BY`. You want the total count across all rows, not the count per group.

Comment: Sir, if i wanted 16 i would have not posted the question.
i want 6 as i am getting 6 rows with group_by..
Also i updated my question so if you can see i get 16 records if i dont use group_by and those records are repeated records.

Comment: Ah, in this case you need to wrap up the original query as subquery like: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT ... GROUP BY ...) AS alias`